# Input shaping for large sequence lengths in temporal convolutional network

Tags: python, keras, time-series, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to implement an anomaly detection scheme using a 1D convolutional autoencoder. This is a time series problem and I have a very large dataset consisting of several files.
Each file constains one data record of 120 seconds with two features sampled at 100 kHz. Meaning I have 12,000,000 datapoints per feature per file.

I'm using the TimeseriesGenerator from Keras in order to prepare the input. But I'm having issues defining the length parameter. Simply giving the actual length of each file makes it impossible to build the model in a reasonable amount of time. I would also assume it generates a huge network.

What are some good techniques for defining the sequence length for data sampled in this way?